# AI that maximizes the storage of rectangular parallelepipeds in a bigger parallelepiped

Tags: optimization, storage

As you can see in the title, I'm trying to program an AI in Java that would help someone optimize his storage.

The user has to enter the size of his storage space (a box, a room, a warehouse, etc...) and then enter the size of the items he has to store in this space. (note that everything must be a rectangular parallelepiped) And the AI should find the best position for each item such that space is optimized.

Here is a list of what I started to do :

- I asked the user to enter the size of the storage space (units are trivial here except for the computing cost of the AI, later on, I'm guessing), telling him that the values will be rounded down to the unit
- I started by creating a 3-dimensional array of integers representing the storage space's volume, using the 3 values taken earlier. Filling it with 0s, where 0s would later represent free space and 1s occupied space.
- Then, store in another multidimensional array the sizes of the items he has to store And that's where the AI part should be starting. The first thing the AI should do is check whether the addition of all the items' volumes doesn't surpass the storage space's volume. But then there are so many things to do and so many possibilities that I get lost in my thoughts and don't know where to start...

In conclusion, can anyone give me the proper terms of this problem in AI literature, as well as a link to an existing work of this kind? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach that gives a good baseline for such problems is [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). The idea is that you do something random. If it improves things, then it is good. If it makes things worse, you still take it with some probability $p$, where $p$ shrinks over time.

The more bad solutions you can rule out beforehand / the smarter you can encode your problem, the better solutions simulated annealing will give.